# Where does firebase authentication store the displayName of its users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication as the authenticator for a .NET app.
I'm not using any other part of Firebase (eg. Firestore, Realtime DB) other than the Authentication.

When I log in using the firebase-ui to get a JWT token issued, it returns a "displayName" as part of the AuthResult which is basically the name field when the user first signed up.

I'm only using the Email / Password sign-in method. Where is this data stored? The Users tab on Firebase Authentication console only shows 5 fields - Identifier, Provider, Created, Signed In and User UID.

Is Firebase authentication storing the user fields like this in some sort of hidden place that I can't access unless I log in as the user?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication stores user profiles in its internal database. Some of the properties are exposed in the Firebase console, but not all of them. You can get all documented properties through the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).